# Почему не работает команда say в perl 5.26

Tags: perl

Почему в скрипте не работает say:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
say " Howdy, word!";
```

Версия вроде бы позволяет:

```
$ /usr/bin/perl -v
This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 0 (**v5.26.0**) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

При запуске ругается:

```
$ ./try.pl
String found where operator expected at ./try.pl line 2, near "say " Howdy, word!""
    (Do you need to predeclare say?)
syntax error at ./try.pl line 2, near "say " Howdy, word!""
```

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо явно включить эту функцию в программу одним из этих способов:

```
perl -e 'use v5.10.0; say 3'

perl -e 'use feature ":5.10"; say 3'

perl -e 'use feature "say"; say 3'
```

Подробнее [тут](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html).

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Почему то думал, что если версия perl 5.10 и выше. то say уже включена.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите хорошую привычку начинать исходники на перле со строчки, сразу после шебанга:

```
use Modern::Perl;
```

По умолчанию она эквивалентна:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
```

Без первых двух строк писать на перле всё равно моветон, а так вобьёте одну строку вместо трёх (впрочем, многие IDE позволяют настраивать шаблоны при создании pl/pm файлов, так что руками и набирать ничего не надо).

Comment: Для этого нужно сначала установить этот модуль=) До этой темы я еще не добрался. Но за совет спасибо, буду изучать дальше. `Can't locate Modern/Perl.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Modern::Perl module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl) at ./try.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./try.pl line 2.`

Comment: @ShuuuuR, для полноценной работы с Perl придётся установить ещё *очень много* модулей, которых нет по умолчанию  :) И с этого стоит (даже нужно) начать.